# Custom Segue Animation Flicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uistoryboardsegue

I am building an application using `UISplitViewController` as my root view controller (as prescribed by Apple). However, I needed a custom view for login / management to be displayed prior to the `UISplitViewController`, so I created a custom `UIStoryboardSegue` that calls some custom animations. I am attempting to recreate the `push / pop` segues through a modal segue, without actually pushing an popping view controllers. I've implemented everything correctly, however, at the end of my animation I have a flicker. Here is a gif of it:

[image: Gif of animation]

Here is my custom Segue's code:

```
- (void)perform {

    UIViewController *srcViewController = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destViewController = self.destinationViewController;

    UIView *prevView = srcViewController.view;

    UIView *destView = destViewController.view;

    UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];



    [window insertSubview:destView aboveSubview:prevView];

    [destView enterRight:0.1 then:^{
        [destView removeFromSuperview];
        [srcViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated: NO completion:nil];

    }];
}
```

And here is my custom animation (Implemented as a category on `UIView`):

```
-(void)enterRight:(float)delay then:(void(^)(void))after
{
    CGPoint moveTo = self.center;
    CGPoint moveFrom = self.center;


    // Grab a point from off the screen
    CGFloat simpleOffscreen = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;


    // come from off the right side (+)
    moveFrom.x = moveFrom.x + simpleOffscreen;

    self.center = moveFrom;
    self.hidden = NO;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:delay
         usingSpringWithDamping:1
          initialSpringVelocity:0.1
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^
     {
         self.center = moveTo;
     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         if (after) after();
     }
     ];
}
```

As you can see in the Segue, I am animating the view into the current view controller, then without animation presenting the actual destination view controller. I think this is where the flicker is introduced, yet I am unsure about how to go about preventing this.

My Storyboard for this custom segue is [image: Here]

Anyone know how to implement this?

Comment: Is this your real code? You call enterRight:then: on destView, but it should be called on self (assuming all the code you posted is in the segue class). Also in enterRight:then:, you have self.center -- a segue doesn't have a center property. Please clarify.

Comment: `enterRight` is a category on `UIView`, so I can reuse this animation on other views. In `enterRight`, `self` refers to the `UIView`, not the `UIStoryboardSegue`.

Comment: How (and from where) are you initiating this custom segue?

Comment: I'm triggering it programmatically on app launch, when the `UISplitViewController` is instantiated, as well as through an `IBAction` in one of the `UISplitViewController`'s view controllers. `[splitViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifier" sender:self]`

Comment: Inside what method are you triggering the segue when the app launches? Are you doing it from the app delegate or from inside a subclassed split view controller?

Comment: From the `App Delegate`, or from an action on one of the two `UINavigationController`'s managed by The splitview controller.